# Wordpress can't access the archives page

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a Wordpress theme with a `archive.php` file, but it doesn't contain any link directly to it.

How can I link directly to this page?

I've tried the following, but it only retrieves a list of the months, not a URL:

```
<?php wp_get_archives(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`archive.php` will used to render author, date, category, tag and taxonomy depends on how you set up your theme.

For instance, if you create link to author page `<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>`, it will use `archive.php` to render the content unless you have `author.php` in your theme.

Please see https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png for more information.